# How to display two divs that contain multiple lines on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display two divs on the same line but one of them contains multiple lines, so the text of the second div is starting after the last line of the first div.

```css
.contact1 {
   display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="test">
        <div class="contact1"><h3 class="contact1"><br>Text1<br>
        Text2<br>Text3</h3></div>
        <div class="contact1"><h3 class="contact1">test</h3></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[image]

But I want "test" to start next to the first line of the first line, like this:

[image]

I would try to move it with the properties `top` or `bottom` but I do not think it is the best fix since I think it might display different when watching the website from different screens (mainly when watching it from the phone).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Use flexbox maybe? `#test { display: flex }`

Comment: That has worked @Baruch, I did not know about ```flexbox```. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to put your `.contact1` elements into a row or a column.
You can control the alignment of the elements in a row or column by changing the `align-items` property. Now it is set to `flex-start` which means align at the top of the row.

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="test">
    <div class="contact1">
      <h3>Text1<br> Text2 <br>Text3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contact1">
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Check [this post of CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to find out what you can do with Flexbox.

Comment: Thanks :) I will take a look! The answer of Baruch has already helped me which is basically the same as yours but I am setting your answer as the best one in order to set my question as solved.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.contact1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="contact1">
    <h3 class="contact1">Text1
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="contact1">
    <h3 class="contact1">test <br>Text2 <br> Text3</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```